# Converting strongly typed object to anonymous one

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a relatively big project where we try to imply the service oriented architecture where possible, but due to that fact today I hit the following problem.
  In my presentation layer (`ASP.NET Web Forms`) I have an `User` object:

```
public class User
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}
  Public string State {get; set;}
  public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
  public string CreatedBy {get; set;}
}
```

There are some more fields in the original project but for this case I think this is not important.
  So in the presentation layer I use this object to show user info on the page, and let the people using the application perform CRUD operations.
  The problem is when I want to create a new user. There is separate `Web Api 2` service project for that - "UserService`so all calls are made to the dedicated action from the`UserService`project and the response is the`ID` of the newly created user and it's initial state in which he was created.
  So to create a new user I do something like this:

```
    public User InsertUser(string username, string email, string createdBy)
    {
        var user = new
        {
            Username = username,
            Email = email,
            CreatedBy = createdBy
        }

        var result = //make call to the user service passing the anonymous object

        user newUser = new User
        {
            ID = result.ID,
            Username = username,
            Email = email,
            CreatedBy = createdBy,
            State = result.State
        }
        return newUser;
    }
```

Due to some reasons which won't be solved in the near future I can't reference some `DTO` object, and the service is expecting either an object from the same type or an anonymous one or it can not deserialize the data. There are two things that really bothers me here - the first one is that I'm creating twice an instance of something which ideally should be just one object of type `User` to which, after the execution of the service I can add the `ID` and `State` like so:

```
newUser.Id = result.Id
newUser.State = result.State
```

Instead I'm creating two obejcts which is far from ideally. Second, one thing that I think could be possible is to create an instance of the `User` from the presentation layer but convert it in a way so the service action is able to deserialize it. Also this seems pretty standard situation, excluding the fact that I can't reference a `.dll` or something.. but yet, maybe there's another solution to this problem that I'm not aware of?

EDIT
On the `Web Api` part the method is something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage InsertUser([FromBody]UserDTO userToInsert)
{
    var user = userToInsert;
    //Call Stored Procedure to Insert the user
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {UserId = user.Id, State = user.State});
    return response;
}
```

and in my client where I call this method just for the sake of make it work I have a nested class:

```
public class UserDetails
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public string State {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of the service method? I am not sure I understand you when you speak about referencing a DLL. Do you mean that you cannot include 3rd party libraries in your project?

Comment: I have `ServiceContracts` project which usually is used to solve this kind of problems. But this particular case is exceptional and I can't reference this project so I need to find a work around for this particular case. It's not worth it to create a whole new project just for this case. At the end I can stick to what I have right now but I really don't want to.

Comment: You really didn't answer my question :) I asked about the signature of the service method. For example `User CreateUser(object info)`. My other question is, can you reference some 3rd party library like AutoMapper for example?

Comment: Ops, sorry, the signature is `public HttpResponse InsertUser([FromBody]UserDTO userToInsert)` I can use automapper!

Comment: So, in your question, you pass an anonymous object, while your service input is a UserDTO. Also, the code in your question accesses a result.ID and result.State, are ID and State part of the HttpResponse type? Can you post a more complete code example?

Comment: See the addition at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at serializing into JSON and then deserializing into an anonymous type object?  Take a look at JSON.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

Comment: hmm I don't quite get it - where I call the service at the end I need to return an object with the correct type (see the method signature) and if you mean to use it on the service side I don't quite get it so maybe it would help to provide example.

Comment: create your strongly typed User (new User()) with your default property selections.  Serialize that strongly typed object into JSON (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm), then deserialize that JSON into an anonymous object (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm).  Use that anonymous object with your service, and return the strongly typed object.

Comment: ahh, I see now. gonna try it tomorrow and if it works will accept your answer. Thanks.